# error while starting react using npm start

Tags: npm

This is the error when i tried to start a react application by `npm start` command

> ```
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall open
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\works\package.json
> npm ERR! errno -4058
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\works\package.json'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-06T11_16_42_885Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: Usually, this type of error occurs with an incompatible version of npm and nodejs. Try to upgrade your npm and node

Answer (score 2):

Usually, this type of error occurs with an incompatible version of npm and nodejs. Try to upgrade your npm and node, if you are using ubuntu os you can do it with below commands:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f

sudo npm install -g n

sudo n stable

sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node//bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs
```

for windows do it like this:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

For more details visit this link here https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade